# How to traverse large array list having array and Objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am having an Array. Each index have Array of Object that have at least 10 properties and I want to map through all the objects and store only ids of those objects in the same order. I have written this code for that.

This is the structure of my data

```
organisationCompanyTalents = [
    [
      {
        id: '',
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
        other1: '',
      },
      {
        id: '',
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
        other1: '',
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        id: '',
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
        other1: '',
      },
    ],
  ];

let companyUserIds = Array();

  organisationCompanyTalents.map(orgCmpTalent => {
    let list = Array();
    orgCmpTalent.map(companyTalent => {
      list.push(companyTalent.company_user_id);
    }),
      companyUserIds.push(list);
  });
```

Now the problem with this code is it is not storing the ids in the same order always some time the larger array is traversed and store first and some time the smaller one. How can i make this efficient so that it return in same order.

Data Fetching part:

```
let organisationCompanyTalents = Array();
var orgTalentReview = Array();

if (companyOrganisations.length > 0) {
  await Promise.all(
    companyOrganisations.map(async org => {
      await this.ComapanyTalentService.getCompanyTalentByOrganisationId(
        org._id,
        companyUser.Company_Id,
      )
        .then(companyTalent => {
          if (companyTalent) {
            organisationCompanyTalents.push(Object.values(companyTalent));
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          throw error;
        });
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use two levels forEach loop as below:

```js
const organisationCompanyTalents = [
    [
      {
        id: 6,
        fname: 'fname6',
        lname: 'lname6',
        other1: 'other16',
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        fname: 'fname4',
        lname: 'lname4',
        other1: 'other14',
      },
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 9,
        fname: 'fname9',
        lname: 'lname9',
        other1: 'other19',
      },
    ],
  ];

let companyUserIds: any[] = [];

  organisationCompanyTalents.forEach(talents => {
      let ids: any[] = [];
      talents.forEach(talent => {
          ids.push(talent.id);
      });

      companyUserIds.push(ids);
  });

  console.clear();
  console.log(companyUserIds);
```

2. Or use map inside a forEach loop:

```js
const organisationCompanyTalents = [
    [
        {
            id: 6,
            fname: 'fname6',
            lname: 'lname6',
            other1: 'other16',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            fname: 'fname4',
            lname: 'lname4',
            other1: 'other14',
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            id: 9,
            fname: 'fname9',
            lname: 'lname9',
            other1: 'other19',
        },
    ],
];

let companyUserIds: any[] = [];

organisationCompanyTalents.forEach(talents => {
    let ids = [];
    ids.push(...talents.map(talent => talent.id));
    companyUserIds.push(ids);
});

console.clear();
console.log(companyUserIds);
```

Comment: Your code is giving me an arrays of ids but i need array of array [ids] each index have list of ids in the same order in witch data is represented above

Comment: Yeah i tried now it gives me array of array[Ids] but again same problem it just changed the sequence what my code was doing.

Comment: I output the answer, it always [[6,4],[9]], I did not see the order changes?

Comment: These ids are the monogdb Object Id and i have more than 50 Obejcts with 10fields when i refresh my page  some time not always it changes the sequence. And one more thing why it is retrun these Object Ids in string ?

Comment: What you mentioned the sequence changes maybe not caused by the code, but the query for MongoDB when you do page refresh, so its the source data sequence changes, make sure the source data is the same sequence when you do page refresh. For string Object ids, I guess it's for unique purpose about MongoDB.

Comment: You were right the problem is with mongodb query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```js
let companyUserIds = [];

  organisationCompanyTalents.map(orgCmpTalent => {
   for (let i=0; i<orgCmpTalent.length; i++){
   companyUserIds.push(orgCmpTalent[i].id)
   }
  });
```

Comment: This code is not working it. I gives me only one ids on ech index i need array of array[ids]